# RUN yarn install --production but still I am seeing all dev dependency

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, yarnpkg

I am building my Dockerfile and I am inside my container and I don’t want to see all dev dependencies.  I was using `RUN yarn install --production` but still I am seeing all dev dependencies. I need to change all prod builds to use `RUN yarn install --production` to build dependencies from lock files and not include dev dependencies.

```sh
FROM node:12 as dev
ARG SVC_NAME
ARG SVC_TYPE
ENV srcpath=/usr/src/app
ENV svcpath=services/${SVC_TYPE}/${SVC_NAME}

# Create app directory
WORKDIR ${srcpath}

COPY . .

# install depdendencies
RUN yarn install  

# build the app
WORKDIR ${srcpath}/${svcpath}

RUN mkdir /tmp/configs

RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]


FROM node:12-alpine as prod
ARG SVC_NAME
ARG SVC_TYPE
ENV srcpath=/usr/src/app
ENV svcpath=services/${SVC_TYPE}/${SVC_NAME}


RUN apk add --update
RUN apk add openssl openssl-libs-static openssl-dev


COPY --from=dev /${srcpath}/packages/ /${srcpath}/packages
COPY --from=dev /${srcpath}/node_modules/ /${srcpath}/node_modules/
COPY --from=dev /${srcpath}/yarn.lock /${srcpath}/yarn.lock
COPY --from=dev /${srcpath}/${svcpath} /${srcpath}/${svcpath}
RUN yarn install --production

 
COPY --from=dev /tmp/configs /tmp/configs

# # set the workdir to the compiled artifact path
# WORKDIR ${srcpath}/${svcpath}/dist/src

WORKDIR ${srcpath}

# set the workdir to the compiled artifact path
WORKDIR ${srcpath}/${svcpath}/dist/src

COPY --from=dev /${srcpath}//yarn.lock /${srcpath}/${svcpath}/dist/src  

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Comment: You `COPY --from=dev` the entire `node_modules` tree; does removing this single line help (you will build a new `node_modules` tree with the later `RUN yarn install --production`)?

Answer (score 1):

you are copying the node_modules from dev, remove that line and you will be okay

Comment: It would be better if you post this in the comments since its not an answer.